# ¿Cómo puedo calcular el MCM de varios números en python?

Tags: python, reduce

Quiero generar más de dos números para calcular el mcm y que al mismo tiempo esos números sean aleatorios.

```
numero1 = int(input('Ingrese el primer número : '))
numero2 = int(input('Ingrese el segundo número: '))
#Y así sucesivamente.

def mcd(numero1, numero2):
    contador = 0
    while numero2 != 0:
        contador = numero2
        numero2 = numero1 % numero2
        numero1 = contador
    return numero1


def mcm(numero1, numero2):
    return (numero1 * numero2) // mcd(numero1, numero2)

print(mcm(numero1, numero2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen diversas maneras de calcular el MCM de dos o más números, ya sea por Euclides, recursión, descomposición, etc., pero en este caso se va a utilizar la función `functools.reduce`.

Definimos la función mcm:

```
def mcm(a, b):
    if a > b:
        mayor_que = a
    else:
        mayor_que = b

    while True:
        if mayor_que % a == 0 and mayor_que % b == 0:
            mcm = mayor_que
            break
        mayor_que += 1

    return mcm
```

Definimos una segunda función que almacenará las variables `x` y `y` que tomarán los números de la lista y los evaluará para pasarlos al resultado.

```
def obtener_mcm_for(lista_almacenada):
        return reduce(lambda x, y: mcm(x, y), lista_almacenada)
```

Finalmente declaramos una lista que se llamará `numbers` en donde se almacenarán nuestros números aleatorios que por medio de un ciclo **for** la variable `num` generará números aleatorios y una condicional evaluará que los números previamente generados, no estén en la lista, en caso de estarlos, se omite y pasa a la siguiente iteración.

```
numbers = []
aleatroio=randint(2, 4)
for i in range(aleatroio):
        num = randint(1, 30)
        if num not in numbers:
            numbers.append(num)
```

Así queda el código completo:

```
numbers = []
aleatroio=randint(2, 4)
for i in range(aleatroio):
        num = randint(1, 30)
        if num not in numbers:
            numbers.append(num)

def mcm(a, b):
    if a > b:
        mayor_que = a
    else:
        mayor_que = b

    while True:
        if mayor_que % a == 0 and mayor_que % b == 0:
            mcm = mayor_que
            break
        mayor_que += 1

    return mcm

def obtener_mcm_for(lista_almacenada):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: mcm(x, y), lista_almacenada)

resultado = obtener_mcm_for(numbers)
print(str(numbers).replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
print(resultado)
```

O si quieren generar ejercicios como lo hago yo, solo es necesario añadir otro ciclo **for** para realizar las iteraciones que necesites:

```
from functools import reduce
from random import randint

insert=int(input('Valor: '))
for i in range(1, insert+1):

    numbers = []
    aleatroio=randint(2, 4)
    for i in range(aleatroio):
            num = randint(1, 30)
            if num not in numbers:
                numbers.append(num)

    def mcm(a, b):
        if a > b:
            mayor_que = a
        else:
            mayor_que = b

        while True:
            if mayor_que % a == 0 and mayor_que % b == 0:
                mcm = mayor_que
                break
            mayor_que += 1

        return mcm

    def obtener_mcm_for(lista_almacenada):
        return reduce(lambda x, y: mcm(x, y), lista_almacenada)

    resultado = obtener_mcm_for(numbers)
    print(str(numbers).replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
    print(resultado)
```

He aplicado lo que he aprendido en estos meses que llevo y creo que sería una pequeña aportación por si alguien tiene la necesidad de buscar específicamente esta pregunta. Espero que le sirva a alguien y lo aproveche. Muchas gracias por leerlo y saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Agregando a [la respuesta de Ulises](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/469284/158880):

Si tienes Python 3.9 o superior también es posible calcular el mcm usando el modulo [math](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/math.html). Dicho modulo nos ofrece la función [lcm](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/math.html#math.lcm). lcm acepta de argumentos una cantidad n de enteros y calcula el minimo comun multiplo de todos ellos.

El código completo quedaría así:

```
from random import randint
from math import lcm as mcm # importamos la función lcm del modulo math con el alias mcm.

insert=int(input('Valor: '))
for i in range(1, insert+1):

    numbers = []
    aleatroio=randint(2, 4)
    for i in range(aleatroio):
            num = randint(1, 30)
            if num not in numbers:
                numbers.append(num)

    resultado = mcm(*numbers) # pasamos cada item de la lista como argumento.
    print(str(numbers).replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
    print(resultado)
```